# How do I debug with Qt Creator on CentOS 6.4?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, debugging, centos

I installed a fresh 64 bit CentOS 6.4 virtual machine using Virtual Box.

I then downloaded the offline installer for Qt 5.6.1, and Qt Creator 4.0.3, for 64 bit Linux distros.

In the course of installing Qt, I was required to install several packages, in order to satisfy the requirements of GCC 4.8+ and Python 2.7+.

However, installation of Python 2.7 on CentOS 6.4 required special steps taken to not screw up the OS, as CentOS MUST use Python 2.6 as its default python. Therefore, python 2.7 was alternatively installed to be launched using "python2.7 sample.py" rather than the original "python sample.py". Here are the steps I took to install it:

https://danieleriksson.net/2017/02/08/how-to-install-latest-python-on-centos/

Qt was successfully built and ran on CentOS 6.4 as shown here:

[image]

However, the debugger doesn't work:

[image]

It requires Python 2.7+, however CentOS's default Python is still 2.6.

I've read that I must re-compile the GDB toolchain to use Python 2.7, but I'm not sure how to do that. I downloaded GDB source from here:

https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/

Extracted it, and attempted to "make" it via the workaround explained in this bug report (pay attention to how they attempt to configure it to use python 2.7)

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-15076

However, it is still not working.

So my question is this: How do I debug in Qt on CentOS 6.4 if the GDb requires Python 2.7 but the OS requires the default Python installation to be 2.6? I tried re-building the GDB toolchain from source but I may be doing it incorrectly.

Sorry if this is a newb question, I picked up Linux about 2-3 days ago. If you need any more information on the OS, environment, or installed packages let me know and I will add them.

Comment: There's almost certainly a Python 2.7 RPM available somewhere that you can install through your package manager.

Comment: I did install Python 2.7 (with special steps) via https://danieleriksson.net/2017/02/08/how-to-install-latest-python-on-centos/ as stated in my post. However, I had to altinstall it, which causes the "python" command to continue to use Python 2.6 (for OS stability) and "python2.7" is the command I use to execute scripts with Python 2.7. The problem is that the system GDB was built to use the "python" command which uses 2.6, and it requires 2.7, but I don't know how to rebuild the GDB to use 2.7 instead of 2.6

Comment: You will need to pick a repository that has **both** python 2.7 and gdb available, then install those, and finally point Qt Creator to use that alternative gdb that should then use the newer python as well.